# jQuery scrolltop - not working after first use

Tags: jquery, uikit, scrolltop

i am using jQuery scrolltop function on this menu: http://goethesternfriseure.de/index.php

the issue is that the scroll function is only working at the first time. after a second click on a link, it scrolls to much to the bottom.

```
$('.sectionlink').click(function(e){
            var sectionelement = $(this).attr("rel");
            var myoffset = $('#'+sectionelement).offset().top;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: myoffset
            }, 800);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

does anyone know whats happening there?

Comment: Which element has the issue? I tested it on Internet Explorer 11 (Modern) and it works OK. It always scrolls to the same position.

Comment: If, after loading the page, you manually scroll to the bottom, and then use the menu, it is displaced in the first try. I guess an element disappearing (the black logo, maybe?) may be causing the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your scroll top is not functioning cause you have to add "px" :

```
$('.sectionlink').click(function(e){
            var sectionelement = $(this).attr("rel");
            var myoffset = $('#'+sectionelement).offset().top;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: myoffset+"px"
            }, 800);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: I've added "px" and also minus 170px to offset position, but were are also differents between the first clicks on every menu-item and a second click on it. 
But then i found the issue: every section had a

   <div id="section5" class="section" data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:'pl7-margin-top'}">

this scrollspy was the issue. dont know why, but now its working..

Comment: Thanks Prolly and Arturo!