# Why won't this smooth scroll to div work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know javascript too well so I apologize if it's some simple fix - but I'm wondering how to get this smooth scroll to div to work. I have a fixed sidebar, with the jump to divs working here:

```
<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <center><h1 class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/pglogo.png"/>
      </a>
    </h1></center>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class="active"><a href="#about-me">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#discovery">Discovery</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#wireframing">Wireframe</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#visual-design">Visual Design</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#project-development">Project Setup</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#test-debugging">Test & Debugging</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#final-product">Final Product</a></li>
      <li><a class="smoothScroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

I also have the javascript smooth scroll function here:

```
   $(function() {
   $('.smoothScroll').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000); 
    return false;
  }
}
   });
 });
```

Any insight onto why this isn't working?

Comment: Does the `target` get determined properly? This seems like a strange way to do things: `$('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']')`

Comment: I"m not sure. I got the smoothscrolling from this pen for reference - http://codepen.io/HZaccaro/pen/zvrgLb

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694822/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-after-first-use

Comment: Your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/29606tku/ EDIT: Click on discovery, that is the only div I added

Comment: @Chris that HTML does not look correct. You used `<div id="discovery">` where it's more likely that you'll want `<a name="discovery">`. It's possible the `id` variant is working.

Comment: @Halcyon It looks for the ID, unless it is not found then it tries to look for something with name=  https://jsfiddle.net/29606tku/1/ see?

Comment: I am guessing he copied the code somewhere and didn't bother to read it.

Comment: Are you linking jQuery on your page?

Comment: jQuery is definitely linked at the bottom of the page. I'm thinking now it may be the way I coded my divs - `<div id="main"><div class="row">
              <div id="discovery" class="col-md-12"><div class="discovery"></div></div>
          </div></div>`

Comment: EDIT: After plugging into jsfiddle, it actually still worked. Now i'm not so sure what's wrong.